# failing to import ctypes on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ctypes

Any ideas why do I get this errorת while trying import `ctypes`:

```
>>> from ctypes import *

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from ctypes import *
  File "C:/Python27\ctypes.py", line 3, in <module>
    libc = ctypes.windll.msvcrt
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'windll'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"C:/Python27\ctypes.py"` indicates you have some stray `ctypes.py` in that path that is loaded instead of the standard library `ctypes` module (which should be `Lib/ctypes/__init__.py` essentially)

That file tries to load `ctypes` (again), ending up loading itself (more or less).

Remove/Rename that file.